# Moving to special marks inside opfunc

Tags: vimscript, original-vim

I'm trying to write a opfunc which surrounds selected motion with two stars (**bold** in Markdown):

```
nnoremap <localleader>b :set opfunc=BoldIt<CR>g@
function! BoldIt(type, ...)
    execute "normal! `[i**"
    execute "normal! `]a**"
endfunction
```

According to `:map-operator` info:

- `[` mark denotes start of text
- `]` mark denotes end of text

In my function just one of the marks works. I mean, if I comment either of the `execute` lines, the other one does the job correctly, as supposed to.

However, when run as shown, stars end in the same position. It's just like if one of the mark get lost. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'm missing?

`:h ']` "To the last character of the **previously changed** or yanked text."

You must keep marks intact until you've done with all of them. Maybe `:lockmarks` or `setline()` or whatever.

Comment: You're right. Insert/append commands were changing the mark. :lockmarks neither work. I checked the doc and it says visual area won't be adjusted, say nothing about opfunc marks though.

Answer (score 3):

@Matt is correct. You have effectively changed the last change marks which is why your approach can not work.

I would suggest you use `c` and `<c-r>` to paste/put the last deleted/yanked text to do your star-surrounding. e.g. `c**<c-r>"**`

I would also recommend following the technique/example laid out by Vim's help (See :h g@)

```
nnoremap <expr> <localleader>b BoldIt()
xnoremap <expr> <localleader>b BoldIt()
function! BoldIt(...)
    if !a:0
      set opfunc=BoldIt
      return 'g@'
    endif
    let type = a:1

    let sel_save = &selection
    let reg_save = @@
    let reg_type = getregtype('"')
    let cb_save = &clipboard
    let visual_marks_save = [getpos("'<"), getpos("'>")]

    let commands = {}
    let commands['line'] = "'[v']g_c**\<c-r>\"**\<esc>"
    let commands['char'] = "`[v`]c**\<c-r>\"**\<esc>"
    let commands['block'] = "`[\<c-v>`]c**\<c-r>\"**\<esc>"

    try
      set clipboard= selection=inclusive
      let cmd = 'noautocmd keepjumps normal! '
      let cmd .= get(commands, type, '')
      silent exe cmd
    finally
      call setreg('"', reg_save, reg_type)
      call setpos("'<", visual_marks_save[0])
      call setpos("'>", visual_marks_save[1])
      let &clipboard = cb_save
      let &selection = sel_save
    endtry
endfunction
```

Note: This may require a newer version of Vim (tested on Vim 8.2.2681)

Comment: Thank you! This approach is certainly easier. Finally, I used yank and <c-r> as you suggest (and restore the registers too, which is indeed a good idea). In vim 8.1 your example fails with "E475: Invalid argument: type='')".

Comment: I am using Vim 8.2.2681. I have changed it to use `...` for parameters since `(type='')` requires a newer version

Comment: Three more changes needed to work in Vim ver 8.1.1401: 1) function getreginfo() doesn't exist, so I replaced that call with @@; 2) modify literal-dict syntax ( `#{}`), which is not supported; 3) in the silent-exe line, there's an extra dot. Now it works. I appreciate your suggestion, it's cleaner and more readable code IMO, and I like the `a:0` trick as well as putting commands into a dict.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, Thank you. I have fixed it up